# Is there around workaround for the "<" operator in the VSCode terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I've recently started learning MySQL but i'm having some issues installing a library (.sql file) I have saved using the VSCode CLI. The command I've used to install the library is:

```
mysql -v < Chinook_MySql_AutoIncrementPKs.sql
```

But when I run this command I get the error message:

```
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
```

If anyone can help with a workaround for the "<" operator, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: define "VSCode CLI" what window?

Comment: @DanielA.White Im using powershell inside VS Code on Windows 10

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the suggestion Martin but this way didn't work for me when installing the library

Comment: which way? There are multiple suggestions in the linked Q

Comment: use cmd /c 'mysql -v < Chinook_MySql_AutoIncrementPKs.sql'

Comment: @nbk Thanks for the suggestion but this route returns the error "The term '/c' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: @MartinSmith I've tried the "Get-content" route and the "cmd /c" root

Comment: OK Maybe too hasty with the close vote then. Have voted to reopen

Comment: @DelroyBrown    i run it in the **terminal** and it runs without a problem-

Comment: @nbk When i run the "cmd /c" command i either get nothing happening or the error message "The term '/c' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: PS C:\Users\me> cmd /c 'mysql -v < Chinook_MySql_AutoIncrementPKs.sql' runs without problems as i saidi in the powershell terminal